# update method angular json server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I would like to update my table without refreshing my page but I don't know how to do it as I am a beginner. In my example I use the table from angular material.

how do I update my page every time I add a new element ?

**service**

```
  public url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/tableInfos';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTableDetails(): Observable<PeriodicElement> {
    return this.http.get<PeriodicElement>(this.url);
  }

  create(name: PeriodicElement): Observable<any> {
   let newName = {name:name}
    return this.http.post<PeriodicElement>(this.url, newName);
  }
```

**ts.file**

```
  ELEMENT_DATA!: PeriodicElement[]
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);

  constructor(private tableService: TableService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.get();
  }

  get() {
    this.tableService.getTableDetails().subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
    });
  }

  add(name: any) {
    this.tableService.create(name).subscribe((data:any) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

**json**

```
{
  "tableInfos": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Hydrogen"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Helium"
    }
  ]
}
```

**interface**

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: I think doing `this.datasource.data = [...data]` should work (refreshes the reference). Otherwise there is `renderRows` and `ChangeDetectorRef` as options.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `this.dataSource.data = res` inside the update function in ts.